# double header stack navigation react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using a StackNavigator in react native app.
The problem is that in my app, it creates two headers ...

[image: double header stack navigator]

I would like to keep the upper one to go back from the screen. Is it possible without recreate the back button manually ?

Screen:

```
class CommandsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    addCommand = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateCommand");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
                <MyList itemsUrl="http://localhost:9000/commands"/>
                <Button title="Ajouter" onPress={this.addCommand}></Button>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

export default StackNavigator({
    CommandsList : {
        screen : CommandsList,
    },
});
```

EDIT :
App.js

```
const navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({headerLeft: <Icon name {'chevron-left'}  onPress={ () => { navigation.goBack() }} />})
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        CommandsList: {
            screen: CommandsList,
        },
        CreateCommand: {
            screen: CreateCommand,
        },
        ListFournisseurs: {
            screen: ListFournisseurs,
        },
        ListAffaires: {
            screen: ListAffaires,
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'CommandsList',
        headerMode:'none',
        navigationOptions:{navigationOptions}
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you add the Navigation Routes for that?

Comment: @PritishVaidya done :) I have this problem on each screen

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, if you want to disable the `header` of the `StackNavigator`, you can apply the config at your [`StackNavigatorConfig`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig) as `headerMode: 'none'`. It is **back propagated** from *Child to Parent, if Parent is none then Child will also not be rendered.*

Therefore for a single header, in your case you should do

```
export default StackNavigator({
    CommandsList : {
        screen : CommandsList,
    },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});
```

For the back button in the Parent Stack, you can create a component as

```
const navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: <Icon name={'arrow-left'} //<== Vector Icon Here
     onPress={ () => { navigation.goBack() }} />

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  RouteConfigs, 
  //... StackNavigatorConfigs,
  navigationOptions
)
```

Comment: I don't understand how to add a navigationOptions without getting an error of navigationOptions ?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator) and add navigation options like mine to the parent stack

Comment: I have edited my App.js as you said (see in my initial post) and still doesn't work

Comment: Just add it as `headerMode:'none',
        navigationOptions`, single object

Comment: I actually haven't error anymore by putting `navigationOptions : navigationOptions` but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You're using `headerMode: none`,in the main stack, it cant show header and button.